# Laravel upload image error: Call to a member function move() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im trying to do simple images upload in Laravel. But when I'm trying to submit form Laravel gives me error:

`Call to a member function move() on a non-object`

Method that stores image:

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $destinationPath = 'uploads';
    $file = Input::file('image');
    $file->move($destinationPath, $file);
}
```

Upload Form:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::file('image',['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

Comment: Try to verify if your file is present : `if($request->hasFile('image')) { /* */ };`.

Comment: It gives nothing just redirects to blank page

Comment: I meant put you current code into the `if` ...

Comment: Im did it. Nothing happend. It just redirects to blank page

Comment: And your file, is it successfully uploaded ?

Comment: Oops yes I forgot to look in folder, sorry. But here is one problem its converts image in 6773.php

Comment: For the name, you can use `$file->getClientOriginalName()` like this : `$file->move($destinationPath, $file->getClientOriginalName());`.